# Retrofit 2 and Spring RestController

Tags: java, spring-mvc, retrofit2

I want to create a project with 3 modules:

- Mobile application (retrofit?)
- Spring endpoint (@RestControler)
- Interface (contains communication entities and **rest methods definition**)

Data classes are easy part as I can use this same parser on both ends, or just don't use any gson / jackson / *son annotations at all.

The problem is:

**How to define Retrofit interface and Spring in a way that do not require manual synchronization of both files?**

Retrofit:

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Spring:

```
public class GitHubService {
  @RequestMapping(value="users/{user}/repos", mehod=GET)
  List<Repo> listRepos(@PathVariable("user") String user);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov I'm afraid I did not.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it Retrofit doesn't support this. But [RestGap](https://bitbucket.org/restgap/restgap) does:

What you're asking for is that you can defined your server interface in Spring MVC - this way, you create an *interface* `IGithubService` with all methods annotated the usual way with `@RequestMapping` etc.
The you can:

- Use that interface for the client
- Implement this interface on the server.

RestGap supports this for interfaced declared with Spring MVC annotations (your case) and JAX RS annotation.